# How to get "Destroy a car" achievement in #DRIVE?

Tags: drive

In the game called #DRIVE on Nintendo Switch, you are required to earn certain "achievements" to unlock new cars. On level 7, one of such achievements is "Destroy a car":

[image]

How do I do that? Simply making an accident ends the game without earning "Destroy a car".

Answer (score 2):

You have to get a snowplough from a junk yard, which makes your car sturdy enough to destroy other vehicles on impact without dying.